# multiple condition for cookie variable in if statement

Tags: php, cookies

I have created two session and want to check the username cookie is created and check first_login =='True'  in if condition.
I have created cookie as

```
 setcookie($userName, '1', time()+(24 *3600)); 
 setcookie('first_login', 'True', time()+(24 *3600));
```

I'm checking as below.value is shown in browser application.but prints 'try again'.Is my if condition is wrong

```
 if(isset($_COOKIE[$userName]) &&  $_COOKIE['first_login']=='True'){
  echo $_COOKIE[$userName];
  echo 'working inside';
 }
 else{
  echo 'Try Again';
 }
```

Comment: May be, try removing one of the conditions from `if` and see what happens. Can't really see any errors in the code.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the cookies until the next request. After you use `setcookie` PHP needs to finish the request and return the data back to the browser before the cookies are saved. Then on the next request PHP will be able to access the cookie values using `$_COOKIE`.

Answer (score 0):

`setcookie("cookiename","cookievalue", $time);` will only set it for the current URL path

Whereas: `setcookie("cookiename","cookievalue", $time, "/");` will set the cookie for all pages on that domain.

If you press <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+J</kbd> in google chrome, and click on the Resources tab, you can find the cookies and the path.